Reledmac quotations
reledmac documentation states that «a quotation environment MUST NOT be opened immediately after a \pstart and MUST NOT be closed immediately before a
\pend».
What if my text chunk happens to be precisely a quotation, for which I need to use a quote environment? What can I add between \pstart and \begin{quote}, and between \end{quote} and \pend?

I don't remember exactly why I have written that 10 years ago in the reledmac handbook. But it should be for good reason. Try with something like relax. But from this time, I have written the possibility to have optional argument in pstart/pend, and I suppose it would be the best solution.
